# 'onCreate' overrides nothing - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Sou novo na área e tinha feito um aplicativo conversor de moeda em *Kotlin* e queria colocar uma *API*, mas não estou conseguindo iniciar mais o aplicativo por conta desse erro no `onCreate`. Já tentei criar uma função com o código e chamá-la no `onCreate`, mas pede um paramentro quando faço isso.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, dolarResult: DolarResult) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btCalcular = btnCalculator
        btCalcular.setOnClickListener {
            val calculo = Integer.parseInt(txtWrite.text.toString())

            fun HideKeyboard() {
                val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                if (imm.isActive) imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)
            }
            
            HideKeyboard()

            val bid = dolarResult.bid

            val resultado = calculo * bid
            val textofinal = "O valor de R$$calculo em USD é $$resultado"
            textView.text = textofinal
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: qual erro está recebendo?

Comment: " 'onCreate' overrides nothing"

Answer (score 0):

Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow.

O método `onCreate` deve receber apenas o parâmetro `savedInstanceState`, sem o `dolarResult`. O erro indica que você tá tentando sobrescrever um método que não existe na classe pai (i.e. não existe um método chamado `onCreate` que recebe um `Bundle` e um `DolarResult` na classe `AppCompatActivity`).

Pra resolver seu problema de compilação, substitua o cabeçalho do seu `onCreate` para:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

Se você precisa desse parâmetro na inicialização da sua Activity, existem outras formas prafazer isso. Mas realmente não dá pra passar ele (nem nada mais) pelo `onCreate`.

Comment: No meu caso eu preciso fazer um calculo entre um valor digitado e um resultado de uma api(que traz em tempo real o preço do dólar)

Comment: Você pode passar os dados que você precisa na inicialização da sua Activity pelo Intent que lançou ela, e tratar no onCreate. Dê uma olhada em https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=pt-br.
Mas sobre o problema descrito acima, declarar o onCreate como mostrado aqui deve resolver.